# MySQL: get differences of each sorted column in set of rows

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here is a simple scenario with table characters:

```
CharacterName GameTime Gold Live
Foo 10 100 3 
Foo 20 100 2 
Foo 30 95 2
```

How do I get this output for the query `SELECT Gold, Live FROM characters WHERE name = 'Foo' ORDER BY GameTime`:

```
Gold Live
100 3
0 -1
-5 0
```

using MySQL stored procedure (or query) if it's even possible? I thought of using 2 arrays like how one would normally do in a server-side language, but MySQL doesn't have array types.

While I'm aware it's probably easier to do in PHP (my server-side langauge), I want to know if it's possible to do in MySQL, just as a learning material.

Comment: I understand the before and the after but I guess I don't see how one table gets to the other. For what reason does the second and third rows go down 100 gold and what makes them lose lives?

Comment: @Stephen, I think SyaZ wants every row to show just the differences to the previous row.

Comment: Exactly Romulo. The new row shows differences between itself and the previous row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution using a temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE characters_by_gametime (
  id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  gold INTEGER,
  live INTEGER);

INSERT INTO characters_by_gametime (gold, live)
SELECT gold, live
FROM characters
ORDER BY game_time;

SELECT
  c1.id,
  c1.gold - IFNULL(c2.gold, 0) AS gold,
  c1.live - IFNULL(c2.live, 0) AS live
FROM
  characters_by_gametime c1
  LEFT JOIN characters_by_gametime c2
    ON c1.id = c2.id + 1
ORDER BY
  c1.id;
```

Of course Eoin's solution is better if your *id* column follows the order you want in the output.

Comment: Good spot. Indeed you'd need to build up a temp table with contiguous ID sequence if one didn't exist already.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an ID on your Table.

```
GameID      CharacterName GameTime    Gold        Live
----------- ------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           Foo           10          100         3
2           Foo           20          100         2
3           Foo           30          95          2
```

If so you could do a staggered join onto itself

```
SELECT
    c.CharacterName, 
    CASE WHEN c_offset.Gold IS NOT NULL THEN c.Gold - c_offset.Gold ELSE c.Gold END AS Gold,
    CASE WHEN c_offset.Live IS NOT NULL THEN c.Live - c_offset.Live ELSE c.Live END AS Live
FROM Characters c 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Characters c_offset
        ON c.GameID - 1 = c_offSet.GameID
ORDER BY
    c.GameTime
```

Essentially it joins each game row to the previous game row and does a diff between the values. That returns the following for me.

```
CharacterName Gold        Live
------------- ----------- -----------
Foo           100         3
Foo           0           -1
Foo           -5          0
```

Comment: This assumes that IDs would be sequential, with no missing IDs etc. Using a sub-query to fetch the ID/GameTime of the previous row would fix that. Other than that... that's how I would do it.

Comment: @Tomalak, but how do you get the previous row with MySQL? I think you'd need a ROW_NUMBER() like function, but it doesn't exist.